# Перевод на новую строку textarea

Tags: html, javascript

Появилась проблема, нужно перенести строку в textarea. Обычно для этого используются &#013;&#010;, но если попытаться сгенерировать содержимое через js то символы перевода строки будут считываться, как текст.

Как лучше выйти их этого положения?

Прикладываю фид для наглядности:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/HappyCougar/nHhs9/1/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("textarea").html("This is my statement one.&#13;&#10;This is my statement2");
```

или

```
$("textarea").html("This is my statement one.\nThis is my statement2");
```

Comment: Спасибо, понятия не имел что .html применим к textarea